# Why gauge field should be vanishing on horizon?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, black-holes, gauge-theory, ads-cft

When considering an AdS spacetime including a black hole, matter field and gauge field, the value of temporal component $A_t$ of the gauge potential $A_\mu$ on horizon always is set be zero, even the matter field is nonzero outsider black hole.

The explanation in paper [Holographic phase transitions at finite baryon density](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0611099) (Page 6) is that the Killing vector on horizon $\partial_t$ vanishes, if the potential $A_\mu$ as a one-form is to be well-defined, then the temporal component $A_t(r_h)$ must vanish on horizon ($r_h$ is the horizon).

**Question**:

1. What the relation between Killing vector and gauge potential lead to the vanishing condition($A_t(r_h)=0$) ?
2. Is that vanishing value for $A_\mu$ on horizon dependent on a special gauge?
3. What about the SU(N) gauge theory in above case?

Comment: Not *quite* sure but: The vector $\partial_t$ is the "basis vector" for the ${}_t$ component of every vector. So if it vanishes, the temporal component of every vector must vanish. But having a $\partial_x$ vanish for any coordinate would indicate to me that you've chosen your coordinate system badly, anyway...

Comment: @ACuriousMind By"every vector must vanish" , do you mean both covariant vector and contravariant vector (0ne-form)?

Comment: Well, depends on your metric - you know that the temporal components of *vectors* vanishes, just lower the index to see what that means for covectors.

Comment: @ZoeRowa The answer is in a paper by Racz and Wald and essentially relies on the existence of a bifurcate Killing horizon and linearity of the gauge field acting on the Killing vector.